# Rearragning dataframe from array to matrix

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following dataframe that shows the temperature for every hour during a weeks period:

```
           Date  Time  Temp
0    2019-01-01     0   7.2
1    2019-01-01     1   6.9
2    2019-01-01     2   6.9
3    2019-01-01     3   6.8
4    2019-01-01     4   6.7
..          ...   ...   ...
163  2019-01-07    19   4.7
164  2019-01-07    20   5.1
165  2019-01-07    21   5.5
166  2019-01-07    22   5.9
167  2019-01-07    23   6.0
```

I want to rearrange it in such a way that each column represents a certain day and each row represent a certain hour of that day. The reason for this is because i later want to plot a heatmap showing the temperature for this time period.

I have written the following code that tries to achieve this:

```
df = pd.read_csv("dataTest.csv",
            usecols=['Date','Time','Temp'])


dfMatrix = pd.DataFrame()
indx = range(int(df['Date'].size/24))

for i in indx:
    
    date = df.iloc[0][0] 
    dfTemp = pd.DataFrame()
    dfTemp = df.loc[df.Date.eq(date)]['Temp']
    dfMatrix[date] = dfTemp
    df = df.loc[df.Date.ne(date)] 

print(dfMatrix)
```

The result I get is the following

```
    2019-01-01  2019-01-02  2019-01-03  2019-01-04  2019-01-05  2019-01-06  2019-01-07
0          7.2         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
1          6.9         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
2          6.9         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
3          6.8         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
4          6.7         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
5          7.3         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
6          6.9         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
7          6.8         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
8          6.6         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
9          6.7         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
10         6.8         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
11         6.7         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
12         6.8         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
13         6.2         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
14         5.8         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
15         5.5         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
16         5.3         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
17         6.2         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
18         6.7         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
19         6.6         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
20         6.1         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
21         6.0         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
22         5.9         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
23         5.6         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

I believe that the problem has to do with the indexing of dfTemp when i try to append it to dfMatrix but I don't know how to solve that issue.

I'm new to both python and dataframes so if there is a much simpler way of solving this, I'd be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just create a pivot table

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Temp',columns='Date',index='Time')
```

Comment: I had a feeling I made it more complicated than necessary. Thank you!